# Can you modify the native browser component for 'Save password'?

Tags: html, browser, remember-me

Have been tasked with modifying the current design of all(not all, but according to what most users are using on our space) native browser 'Remember my password' components. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so(or not so) any sources would be appreciated, for the life of me I cannot find any answers. Example below.

[image: phone emulator chrome login to reddit, asked if want to save password]

To reiterate, I'm not asking if it is possible to 'stop' or 'trigger' the 'remember password' component, I was asking if it was possible to control the design.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is just: no, you cant edit the design, this is managed by the browser, edge, chrome, firefox... eachone has his own design for that.

Answer (score -1):

The browser is what is executing your code, so no you cannot change browser functionality from your code. If you could it would be an unimaginable security flaw.

You can however change your website in a way where it wouldn't ask to save the password - making the browser not use the save password functionality.

That can be achieved by adding an `autocomplete="off"` option to your form..

```
<form id="loginForm" action="/login" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just shows another way to not do it.